# Unable to burn an ISO image to a DVD-R

Tags: windows-7, dvd, burning

I have downloaded **ubuntu 13.04 iso** recently. When I tried burning it onto a **DVD-R** using **Windows Disc Image Burner**, the blank disc which I inserted was ejected automatically. I've tried a bunch of times. I'll right-click on my iso and select **Burn disc image**, the burner window will open. The initial status will be **To start burning the disk image,click Burn**. Then I'll click on **Burn**. The status will turn to **Checking disc...**. Two or three seconds from here the status will change to **There is no disc in your disc burner. Insert a blank recordable disc, and then try again.** Simultaneously my disc will be ejected. Whenever I try to burn it, it just gets ejected this way. Help me overcome this. What is the problem with my burner?

Comment: What hardware (blank disc and DVD writer) is involved?

Comment: I was using a **single sided/single layer DVD** (of Sony Corporation) and I was using the DVD writer which is a built-in writer came along with my **IBM 8115 KQB** (ThinkCentre M52) CPU. Other than this, not much idea about the DVD writer. @DanielB

Comment: What does Ubuntu have to do with this? Did you test it with Ubuntu?

Comment: Try using [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/index.php?act=Download). If you're still unable to burn the ISO image, at least you can use it to retrieve more technical details about the blank media and the burner.

Comment: Thanks @and31415. Used ImgBurn as you suggested. It didn't work as well. But got the answer for why I wasn't able to burn my DVD. ImgBurn provided details like my DVD writer (DVD/CD-RW) don't support burning DVD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure of your DVD writer supporting CD/DVD burning before you decide to burn it. It is very simple to know whether your computer can burn CDs and DVDs. Make use of the following guidelines.

> **FOR WINDOWS  OS USERS:**
>
> Just check the name on your CD/DVD drive icon.
>
> If the drive says **DVD/CD-RW Drive**, it can **play and write to CDs** and **play but not write to DVDs**.
>
> If the drive says **DVD RW Drive**, it can both **read and write to CDs and DVDs**.
>
> ---
>
> **FOR LINUX OS USERS:**
>
> Usually the linux distro won't be equipped to interrogate your hardware. To do that you will need to open your **Terminal** and enter **`sudo apt-get install libcdio-utils`**. This will download and install the necessary tools for fetching out the info about your DVD drive. Now enter **`cd-info`** in the Terminal. It will reveal the CD/DVD drive info including the read and write capabilities.

Also, be sure of your file not broken in case of an iso kind. As well, use an undamaged CD/DVD.

Answer (score 1):

The times I've had this problem it was due to a bad disk, I know it is a silly question but have you tried a different DVD?

As for software ImgBurn is a good choice.

Comment: Yes. I have. I tried three newly bought empty DVDs. @Zeke

Comment: People online keep referring to bad discs but I've tried a half dozen or so (trying to burn the Ubuntu ISO) and it always results in an unrecognizable disc.

Answer (score -1):

Check if your DVD Burner is in line with the DVD, if you see X4 or X8 it will burn with out error, if it is a blu ray DVD burner, X16 will work. if it can read a DVD R- or + it indicates that your disk might be X16. we focus too much on the software or firmwaRE. I tested a disc tyo record. mine is a DVD/CD Burner.it works well with disks labelled X4 not the X16. try out this solution.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser!  Please note that this question is over two years old, and the OP answered his own question, so it is unlikely the OP will try a new solution.

Comment: Burners can burn at speeds below their maximum.